# Selection of entries that have only two words with SQL wildcards

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a table `place` that has a column called `title`. I want to select only those data which have only two words.

For example, if the table consists of a title named `"Buckingham Palace"`, I would have wanted it in my resultant table rather than having titles such as `"Tower Of London"` or `"Berlin"`. How can this be done in MySQL?

Note: Any title that has only one space in between will be considered. For example, `"St. Marc"` should also be selected.
I have tried

```
select title from place where title not like '% % %'
```

I still get results in the table like St. Bishop's Palace (the entries which usually have words like *St.* or *Mt.*).

When I try that query with just a space extra added, I get unnecessary entries like *Tower of God* and *Palace of Parliament*.

```
select title from place where title not like ' % % % '.
```

Comment: You must define strictly the term "word". For example, define "in the words" or "out of the words" chars array.. `1-st place` - two words? `place,1` - two words? In general - use [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp).

Comment: @Akina i've edited the question, could you review it again and tel me about your _REGEXP_ solution.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT title 
FROM place 
WHERE title REGEXP '^ *[^ ]* *[^ ]* *$';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=afb7f92afa54555d6ccdbd51ae621a1c)

---

> some explaining words about your regular expression, would help others – nbk

The explanations can be found [there](https://regex101.com/r/CAN6bq/1) in "EXPLANATION" window. Anycase I cannot explain better..

Comment: some explaining words about your regular expression, would help others

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you consider the space character as the delimiter to separate words (as per your examples) this query should do what you're looking for:

```
SELECT title
FROM Place
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(title), ' ', 2)) = 0 -- Titles that don't have more than 1 space
    AND CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(title), ' ', 1)) > 0 -- And Titles that have at least 1 space (effectively this conjoined predicate results in Title's with exactly 1 space, that isn't at the start or end, aka two words)
```

There's probably a simpler solution, but this will remove trailing and leading spaces from the `title` column then filter out anything that has more than 1 space (the first predicate) **and** filter out anything doesn't have at least 1 space (the second predicate). Also this syntax is only for **MySQL**, as you requested, but you also tagged your question as PostgreSQL (so you should either remove that tag or update the question with the information you need on PostgreSQL).

Comment: what about using the 'LIKE' operator? Could tell me a solution by using that also?

Comment: @Shinichi I don't believe that's possible with only the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: alright ...thanks

Comment: @Shinichi No problem! Alternatively you can use the `REGEXP` function to use regular expressions to parse out the `title` column too. (Also feel free to accept this answer if it is helpful so other users with a similar question see it's verified.)

Comment: can you show me the solution with `regexp` function cause it is showing _substring_index is not a recognized built-in function name_ error or even with `LIKE` would work.